# How to update the dropdownlist in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I tried to update the drop down list by using ajax call to web method in asp.net as given below:

`<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCustomers" runat="server" multiple="multiple"></asp:DropDownList>`

```
   $('#btnSelected').click(function(){
        var name= $("#<%=ddldistrict.ClientID %>").val();
       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "reportutil.aspx/LoadMandals",
            data: '{name: "' + name + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
      

         });
    });
   
    });
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        var ddlCustomers = $("[id*=ddlCustomers]");
        ddlCustomers.html("");
   
        $.each(response.d, function () {

                ddlCustomers.append($("<option optgroup= " + this['option'] + " > </option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
  
        });
        $('[id*=ddlCustomers]').multiselect({
            enableClickableOptGroups: true,
            enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            enableFiltering: true

        });
        
   var name = $("#<%=ddldistrict.ClientID %>").val();

        alert(name[0]);
       
        
    };
  
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=ddlCustomers.ClientID %>").change(function () {
            
            alert($("#<%=ddlCustomers.ClientID %>").val());
           

        });
       
     });
```

Here the data is coming and binding first time only. If I changed the option and send to the web method, from that method I'm getting the result but that data is not binding to drop down list, but if I remove multi select  from Javascript then it is binding. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btnSelected').click(function () {
    var name = $("#<%=ddldistrict.ClientID %>").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "reportutil.aspx/LoadMandals",
        data: JSON.stringify({ name: name }),
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $("[id*=ddlCustomers]").empty();
            var appendData = "<option value=''>--Select--</option>";
            for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
                if (response.d[i].Name != "") {
                    appendData += "<option value ='" + response.d[i].ValueFieldName + "'>" + response.d[i].TextFieldName + "</option>";
                }
            }
            $("[id*=ddlCustomers]").append(appenddata1);
        },
        error: function () { alert("error"); }
    });
});
```

Comment: but i want to use multi select options also. how to do that. please help me

Comment: Hey @rammi , got your problem and i've made a solution for you. hope it'll work for you.

Go to [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/610vmy/) and get the code with preview.